# How can I use XSLT to replace a keyword in formatted HTML with a HTML tag?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to add a hyperlink to a keyword in HTML-formatted text stored in an XML document.

XML fragment:

```
...several parent layers...

<Note>

  <NoteItem>
    <NoteText>Heading of note<br/>
Body of note blah blah keyword blah blah.<br/>
May contain more lines.</NoteText>
    <DisplaySequence>1</DisplaySequence>
  </NoteItem>

  <NoteItem>
    <NoteText>Heading of note2<br/>
Body of note2 blah blah blah blah.</NoteText>
    <DisplaySequence>2</DisplaySequence>
  </NoteItem>

</Note>

...etc...
```

Desired output:

```
...more HTML...

<ul>
  <li>
    Heading of note<br/>
    Body of note blah blah <a href="http://127.0.0.1/">click here</a> blah blah.<br/>
    May contain more lines.
  </li>
  <li>
    Heading of note2<br/>
    Body of note2 blah blah blah blah.
  </li>
</ul>

...more HTML...
```

Original attempt at XSLT template. This adds the HTML tag, but loses all the existing formatting.

```
  <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$by" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Second attempt. This preserves the existing formatting, but adds the new HTML as display text rather than a functioning tag.

```
  <xsl:template name="string-replace-formatted">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="$by" />
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-formatted">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Template being called:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl fo" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:template match="/root/longpath/Note">
    <xsl:if test="NoteItem">

<ul>
  <xsl:for-each select="NoteItem">
    <xsl:sort select="DisplaySequence" />
      <li>
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-formatted">
          <xsl:with-param name="text">
            <xsl:copy-of select="NoteText/node()" />
          </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="replace">keyword</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="by">
          <![CDATA[<a href="https://127.0.0.1">click here</a>]]>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ul>

    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, I'm looking for the best of both worlds - how can I preserve the existing HTML tags and add a new HTML tag? Is it possible with a generic template like I have here (so it can be reused for other tags), or will I need a single-purpose template that has constant values for the string found & replaced?

Comment: Please provide a way to reproduce the problem you report - see: [mcve]. From your description it seems you are calling the template with the entire content of the  element, instead of individual text nodes.

Comment: You haven't shown how you are invoking your named template. The key here is that you need to process each text node individually, and that is most easily done by using recursive descent template rules, the standard XSLT processing pattern.

Comment: updated example code - does this help?

Answer (score 1):

With xslt 1.0 you could try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="NoteText//text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="make-link">
      <xsl:with-param name="linktext" select="'keyword'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="link" >
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/"/>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="make-link">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
    <xsl:param name="linktext" />
    <xsl:param name="link" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $linktext)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($text,$linktext)" />
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/">
          <xsl:value-of select="$linktext" />
        </a>
        <xsl:call-template name="make-link">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$linktext)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="linktext" select="$linktext" />
          <xsl:with-param name="link" select="$link" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This too will not work with an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: Changed the code. I wonder if one uses Saxon HE and xslt 1.0 version , why it does not complain...

Comment: Why should it? It's an XSLT 3.0 processor and it works according to the XSLT 3.0 specification. The only obligation it has when it sees `version="1.0"` is to interpret XPath expressions using XPath 1.0 compatibility mode **as defined in the XPath 3.0 specification**. It will not attempt to fully emulate an XSLT 1.0 processor with all its behavior and limitations.

Comment: There are much more differences than only xpath between 3.0  and 1.0.

Comment: Not sure what your point is. You asked about the expected behavior of an XSLT 3.0 processor when it encounters an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet.

Comment: This won't work for my use-case. I need it wrapped in a for-each so I can sort the notes in order. And I need to output them as a dot list (html elements ul & li). Tried putting the template definition/call in various places & it always fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy job for XSLT 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:template match="NoteText//text()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., 'keyword')" mode="wrap-match"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:match" mode="wrap-match">
    <a href="http://localhost/">{.}</a>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 3 is available with Saxon for the Java platform, the .NET platform, with SaxonC for Python/C/C++, with SaxonJS for Node.js and the browser.